# UWP WinUI3 - Side Notification Panel

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I am trying to build a UWP application. User can perform actions like upload/download/rename/delete files. I want to maintain the status of these actions in a side notification panel (Similar to the one-drive app or azure-portal).

With the click of the notification button, a side panel should pop up from the right side of the UWP application and contain the status of the performed tasks. If we click the notification button again, the side panel should close. Any suggestions on how I can proceed?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview) can have items in the left and show contents in the right. Do yo think this fits your requirements?

Comment: Hi Andrew. I have seen this one. It doesn't fit our solution as we already have a navigation view on the left that contains other things. I prefer a similar one on the right side that opens to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the `SplitView`.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<SplitView
    x:Name="StatusPane"
    PanePlacement="Right">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <!-- Your status of performed tasks here... -->
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Status" />
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open/Close Status" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</SplitView>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.StatusPane.IsPaneOpen = !this.StatusPane.IsPaneOpen;
}
```